# Multiple dynamic classes with amp-bind

Tags: amp-html, amp-bind

How do you include multiple dynamic classes in amp-bind?

For example:

```
<div [class]="condition1 ? 'classA' : 'classB'" [class]="condition2 ? 'classA' : 'classD'"></div>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can return a single string containing multiple classes inside your amp-bind expression:

```
<div [class]="(condition1 ? 'classA' : 'classB') + ' ' + (condition2 ? 'classA' : 'classD')">...</div>
```

Comment: For example, such code I write when the second class I get through amp-bind-macro: 
`[class]="'seat-data' + ' ' + getStringPart(ampState.seatsArray[ampState.active], '2')"`

Answer (score 0):

If you are referring to CSS classes, you can refer [here](https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/components/amp-dynamic-css-classes).

The following CSS classes specifically `amp-referrer-*` and `amp-viewer` adds to the AMP Dynamic CSS Classes extension's `<body>` element.

You can can out the sample project provided [here](https://ampbyexample.com/components/amp-dynamic-css-classes/) to have a view on how it is implemented.